# Is there a way in which multiple threads can print the current time(Time in milli seconds) exactly same?

Tags: java, multithreading, datetime, threadpool, executorservice

Using Executor Service's I need to run 10 threads. And each of these threads should print the current time in milliseconds and I need to ensure that all these threads always print the exact same time.
I have tried using CyclicBarrier but it does not work.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Would you please add a code example of your best attempt?

Comment: Capture a time value up front, give it to all the threads and have them print it. Now *"all the threads always prints the exact same time"*, as requested. Sure, after running for 10 minutes they will still print the starting time, but you did say they should always print the *same* time.

Comment: As @Andreas said, the sure way is when all the threads get the “current” time from the same source. They may refresh their time (after 10 minutes or a lot earlier) if only you make sure they all do it when they do.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a `CountDownLatch` to achieve what you are trying;

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestApp {
    private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 10;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(THREAD_COUNT);
        for(int i=0;i<THREAD_COUNT;i++) {
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                countDownLatch.countDown();
                try {
                    countDownLatch.await();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Result

> ```
> pool-1-thread-5 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-8 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-4 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-6 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-1 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-2 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-9 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-3 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-7 - 1586432194060
> pool-1-thread-10 - 1586432194060
> ```

Comment: Good effort, but nothing in this program _guarantees_ that all ten threads will _always_ read the same value from the clock.

Comment: Yes, this is the closest I could get. I exactly same value needs to be in all threads then needs to pass one miliseconds value from outside.